# Cannot get Delete method to work. I've tried debugging and it doesn't seem to even direct to the method

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a generated view with a list of "to do items" I am trying to create the Delete method for the generated delete link. I have created a ListController which already handles adding to the list database. Now I am trying to get the list to delete items. here is my ListController:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MyBasicListApp2.Models.DB;
using MyBasicListApp2.Models.EntityManager;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace MyBasicListApp2.Controllers
{
    public class ListController : Controller
    {
        // GET: List
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // First I create a todolist action that is used to receive the default ToDoList page
        // Second I create a post todolist action for submitting form info on the page.
        // In the method I check to see if the filled out viewmodel contains valid model data state
        // If data is valid then I create an EntityManager object (contains logic method) so I can use
        // the addtolist method I made in the ListManager (EntityManager).
        // Next I will authenticate the form and set an auth cookie for incase the current session does
        // not include cookies.

        public ActionResult ToDoList()
        {
            return View();
        }


        // In the post I pass in the viewmodel that the view will use to collect information
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ToDoList(tblBasicList LVM)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                ListManager LM = new ListManager();
                // Addtolist is a method belonging to ListManager and can only be called if ListManager 
                // object is created in the current context.
                LM.AddToList(LVM);
                return RedirectToAction("MyToDoList", "Home");

            }
            return View();
        }

        // Delete method
        // First create the actionresult for the edit call
        // Get method
        public ActionResult Delete()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Delete(int BasicListID)
        {
            using (MyBasicListAppEntities db = new MyBasicListAppEntities())
            {
                ListManager LM = new ListManager();
                LM.Remove(BasicListID);
                return RedirectToAction("MyToDoList", "Home");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I have a separate class handling my entity framework methods for add and delete:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using MyBasicListApp2.Models.DB;

namespace MyBasicListApp2.Models.EntityManager
{
    public class ListManager
    {
        public void AddToList(tblBasicList LVM)
        {
            using (MyBasicListAppEntities db = new MyBasicListAppEntities())
            {
                tblBasicList TBL = new tblBasicList();
                TBL.InputDate = LVM.InputDate;
                TBL.InputItem = LVM.InputItem;
                TBL.InputImportance = LVM.InputImportance;
                TBL.ItemCompletion = LVM.ItemCompletion;

                db.tblBasicLists.Add(TBL);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }     
        public void Remove(int id)
        {
            MyBasicListAppEntities db = new MyBasicListAppEntities();

            tblBasicList objDelete = db.tblBasicLists.Find(id);
            db.tblBasicLists.Remove(objDelete);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

I start from the "MyToDoList.cshtml" view:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyBasicListApp2.Models.DB.tblBasicList>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "MyToDoList";
}

<h2>MyToDoList</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.InputDate)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.InputItem)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.InputImportance)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ItemCompletion)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InputDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InputItem)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InputImportance)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ItemCompletion)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.BasicListID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.BasicListID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "List", new { id=item.BasicListID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

From here I select one of the items from the list ( I have about 6 in there right now. the `add` method works perfectly). But when I click the Delete button I get a "resource not found" error. It won't even redirect to the Delete view which I am having a hard time figuring out why. The goal is to direct to the delete page, hit delete for the chosen item and then be redirected back to the "MyToDoList" page. Any ideas?

Comment: Ok so adding a new overload to the action link:                                                   @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "List", new { id=item.BasicListID }, new { })            It now directs to the delete view. But none of the data is transferred over with it. and when I hit delete  I get a           The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'BasicListID' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a short answer, change the Delete method (for HTTP GET) to

```
public ActionResult Delete(int id)
{
     tblBasicList todoItem = FindTodoItem(id); //with whatever method to get that todo item
     return View(todoItem);
}
```

I guess you are trying to create an web app with ASP.NET MVC. There are some naming convention for controller/view/model. I would recommend some tutorials for your reference in this link http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started

Comment: This is essentially what I needed to do. So basically I made a get and post method for delete. When I was hitting the delete button it was calling the get delete action but not the post. I deleted the post and changed the get to kind of what you said:                                                            public ActionResult Delete(int id)
 {
 ListManager LM = new ListManager();
 LM.Remove(id);
And then I called the Remove method (see above) from my listManager class. Now it just deletes them from the list in the view. I need to figure out how to get the confirm delete page.

Comment: @Devon I think the deletion procedure you mentioned is correct. No need to delete the Delete method for HTTP POST. The reason I added a parameter 'id' for Delete method for HTTP GET is that it's required by the default ASP.NET MVC routing rule. As I said there are some naming convention rules in asp.net mvc. If you create the controller & views with scaffold template (with Entity Framework for CRUD) in visual studio, VS will create all code for you. That's why I suggest to have a look at the asp.net mvc tutorial. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a Get and a [HttpPost] for a Controller like Delete since there is no actual view for it.

```
   public ActionResult Delete(int BasicListID)
    {
        MyBasicListAppEntities db = new MyBasicListAppEntities();
        tblBasicList objDelete = db.tblBasicLists.Find(id);
        db.tblBasicLists.Remove(objDelete);//this can actually be simplified 
        return RedirectToAction("Home");
    }
```

You only need to redirect it to the controller like home without passing the list to it, the Home controller will take care of passing the list.

Comment: Nah that didnt work. First I got an ambiguous error so I changed the perameter to int? BasicListId, then I got a needs to be tested if null error so I threw it into a try catch: try { if(BasicListID != null) { remove object } catch (throw new error exception(e.ToString());}                                                                          
Now this is just giving me a resource cannot be found error. But I am further along now and I appreciate the help!

Comment: So stepping through it with the debugger, when I get to the try catch the value is always coming up as null